# Installing homebrew but it gives 404 errror

Tags: homebrew

I am trying to download homebrew from brew.sh for mac, but when I paste the command in the terminal it says `curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404`. The command I am using is `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`. Is the download site currently down?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to this [github issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/install/issues/645), there is an issue with Github. The Homebrew website has been updated and instead of using the HEAD branch we now use the master branch.

Instead of

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

Use

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

To uninstall Homebrew, use the master branch as well

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall.sh)"
```